# Open check.php by Opening Folder Directory using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a Folder named `F_Check`, which contains `check.php` and some other PHP files.

I want the User to show or redirect to `check.php`, if user opens `F_Check` directory. Means, where `index.php` should open, `check.php` should be open. But, after opening other PHP files, it should not redirect to `check.php` file.

I search for it, but did not find any Specific code, But I well know that it can be done using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Directoryindex` directive in `/F_Check/.htaccess` . Create an htaccess file in the folder if it doest already exist there and put the following lines :

```
DirectoryIndex check.php
RewriteEngine on
```

This will set `/check.php` as directory index handler for the folder.

You can read more about  **Directoryindex** directive on  Apache mod-dir documentation 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html